# How to make executerService.shutdown wait for nested threads invokation

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

So I have a function which looks like this

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2000);
Boolean getMore = true;
try{
    While (getMore) {
       JSONObject response = getPaginatedResponse();
       int[] ar = response.get("something");
       if (ar.length > 0) {
           // loop through the array and invoke executorService.submit() for each
       }
       else { getMore = false; }
    }
    executorService.shutdown();
    try {
            System.out.println("waiting for tasks to complete, termination starting at : "+java.time.LocalDateTime.now());
            executorService.awaitTermination(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new Exception("loading was interrupted... thread pool timed out!");
        }

} catch (Exception) {
   System.out.println("Fatal error");
}
```

My issue is that the each of these threads invoke x number of threads, which in turn each call an API and processes its response, the implementation stops execution after all the "First-level" threads gets fired, but not necessarily all the second level ones, which is crucial for my program, how or where can I invoke the executerService.shutdown() to make sure that all the threads were called.

Comment: 2000 threads will be counterproductive unless you have a system with hundreds of processors.

Comment: @JimGarrison Yeah, I'm running it on a system that can support it, no worries :D

Comment: Sometimes, if you can't find a library that does what you want, you have to write the code yourself. If you want to wait for all of the threads to complete, then why not declare an `AtomicInteger numLiveThreads = new AtomicInteger(0);` that you increment just before creating each new thread, and have each thread decrement it just before it dies? Then, you can wait for them all to die by polling until `numLiveThreads` becomes zero.

Comment: I don't see any call to submit, so question does not explain what "first level" and "second level" threads mean - that will be where you problem is. Do you have minimal code which reproduces this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can put   `executorService.shutdown();`  inside finally block of exception

Comment: how would that differ? It still wouldn't wait for the nested threads